# gnupg: Use specific key for symmetric encryption of stdin

Tags: gnupg

I'm looking for a way to use gpg2 to symmetrically encrypt stdin and send it to stdout.

```
echo "Unencrypted" | gpg2 -d -symmetric
klgkljfgkls... [encrypted]
```

I could not figure out how to specify which of my keys should be used for this. The example above I guess uses the first key in the key ring.

Comment: `-d` is _decrypt_. `-c` or `--symmetric` (two hyphens not one) is symmetric encrypt -- with entered passphrase only not keyring key, as @Jens answered -- and `-e` is publickey encrypt, normally with the _recipient's_ key, but you can specify your own id as the/a recipient. It is _signing_ that defaults to your first keyring key unless configured otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetric encryption does not rely on public/private keys (so there is no need and possibility to select a key). It does not use a key in your key ring *at all*.

The symmetric session key (which would be encrypted with a public key without the `--symmetric` flag) is derived from a passphrase instead.

Comment: alright, this makes sense to me now.

Comment: This answer could perhaps take more care to clarify which statements are about symmetric cryptography *per se* and which are about GnuPG.  Symmetric cryptography most certainly relies on shared secret keys; GnuPG, however, has the peculiarity that its symmetric encryption mode is completely passphrase-based.